# Laravel 5.5 and VueJS, use both together correctly in a tags app

Tags: laravel, dom, vue.js, tags

I guess this question has already been posted in different forms over time, but I still didn't find the answer I'm looking for:

I'm having trouble implementing vueJS in my Laravel app, I want to keep server and front-end very much separated but in this case it doesn't seem so easy. I have the classic blog project, where every article has some tags associated with it, so there's a classic many-to-many relationship and everything is set.

When I edit an article, I wanna have a section where all the tags are displayed and also you can add a new tag (very stackoverflow-like), what I wanna achieve is that my Javascript (and so my vue) only manages the rendering of those tags on the page, so that when I enter in the edit page I can see all associated tags, BUT, i only want to edit the input tag inside my form, I don't want to do a POST request in Vue, I want to keep it PHP, I want laravel validation, I don't want to write another one for the javascript.

I want javascript to only edit the DOM when I want to add a tag, so that I insert a new one and it immediately gets pushed inside the already existing array of tags, so in real-time the tags are updated, but when I submit the form it is my PHP that handles the server request, not vue, and this for now seems impossible because in order to update the tags correctly when adding one (or removing one), the data inside vue needs to have a list of tags, otherwise it won't work.

This means I have to create a new route (for example `/tags/{article_id}`) and a new controller function in order to return tags associated with that article, so this also means that I can't give to PHP the tags that I rendered (cause for example they're in a list, not an input select (due to the appearence I want to give)) isn't there a cleaner way to do this?

I'm trying to wrap my head around vuejs but sometimes it feels like stuff would be easier in jQuery (?), I don't know... I hope I explained myself correctly.

Comment: That is officially the longest run on sentence I've read all day. Here (.......) use some of these extra periods I've got lying around.

Comment: Please post some code for people to comment on – otherwise your question may be closed for being too open ended. For help look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well my question is more about the approach to write the code...